# Why does Android Studio download gradle each time a new gradle project is imported?

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Why does Android Studio download gradle every time I try to import a new project?

Initially, I imported one gradle project for which Gradle 2.1 was auto-downloaded. Subsequently, for a second project import, it downloaded Gradle 1.10. Now again while importing a third project, it has downloaded Gradle 2.2.1.

What is happening?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Projects can declare which Gradle they require to run (see `gradle.properties` file in `gradle` directory in the root of the project).

Android Studio uses this information to download and run the right version (it's actually not Android Studio, it's the [Gradle Wrapper](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html) running inside it). And it's a good thing.

*What you can do?*

1. Wait. Once you have the version downloaded in `~/.gradle` directory, it will be used for any project declaring the same version. It's one-time cache.
2. Disable the usage of the wrapper when you import the project. **I really recommend against it!** You project might not build because of that.

Comment: As for me I want to manage and download my own versions of Gradle, downloading a new version of gradle each time consume too much disk space just to store almost same files again and again...

Answer (score 7):

Same happens to me.

The answer of JBaruch is allright.

1.- When you're opening a file on the option Gradle project: select the build.gradle that cames on your project

2.- Select the option "Use local grade distribution" and in Gradle home option; go and select in C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\gradle-2.2.1

It will not ask you to download it again (except if needs other version)

Comment: Yes. Recently, I was trying out some Udacity Nanodegree courses and I was quite annoyed about this gradle behavior whenever I import a new project. But the 'Use local gradle distribution' option saved me.

Answer (score 3):

...well, here's what I normally do to speed up the initial build on opening a project (target):

1- open a project you already have working and open the file gradle-wrapper.properties a copy the following line (your project most likely will have a different version):

```
distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7-bin.zip
```

2- paste it and replace the code on the same file on the target project
3- open the file build.gradle (project code) from a project you already have working and copy the following classpath, (again, your project most likely will have a different version)

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.0-alpha15'
    // ...
}
```

4- paste it on the same file on the target project

This way you can speed up the build of the target project while avoiding the usual 100Mb or so Gradle download.

Answer (score 3):

It usually downloads the Gradle updated version & and external dependencies for each project rather than fetching it from the cache.

So follow these steps:-

Go to settings

Search for Gradle

Untick Download External Dependencies Option.

[image: Untick Download External Dependencies]

Answer (score 2):

Basically it downloads the Gradle build files for your current project according to its version and this whole work is done by your gradle wrapper which actually looks towards the basic requirement for your project and downloads the files according to that so  whenever you are going to use any another projects of same version or with same requirements then it will not download any additional file at that time.Its just a one time shot!!!!

Comment: It doesn't answer the question